# How to install two separate versions of an app from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with the Firebase chat project from github.
I am trying to make 2 apps, one client-side and one admin-side.
I have two copies of the project with different project names and different app names.
Still, I can't run both on the same device with android studio. Running one requires uninstalling the other.
I understand it might be a pretty basic thing, but any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: can you check their Package name ? i doubt their package name are same

Comment: Need to be 2 different package name, then in this case, your firebase chat can't link to 2 different app. My suggestion is merging both app into 1

Comment: Check out this link, build variant might be what you looking for  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: Application id should always be unique in Android App. Change `applicationId` in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Comment: thank you very much everyone. I solved it from Wendy Liga's answer below.
I did not make the changes in the applicationId  in build.gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you need to do is change package name on App `Build.Gradle`, find `applicationId` and change one of your project package name

hopefully it works

Comment: thanks a lot Wendy, this is exactly what I didn't do.

Comment: happy to hear that

Answer (score 1):

In your app level `build.gradle` file under `android` tag define different product flavors for different app.
Please find the below code and do changes according to your project.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    flavorDimensions "default"
    project.archivesBaseName = "Visualogyx";
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv('KEYSTOREPATH'))
            storePassword System.getenv("VISUALOGYX_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("VISUALOGYX_KEYALIAS_NAME")
            keyPassword System.getenv("VISUALOGYX_KEYALIAS_PASSWORD")
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.visualogyx.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionCode 778899
            versionName "v.1.1.BUILD_NUM"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "VisualogyxDEV"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", System.getenv("VISUALOGYX_HOST_DEV") 
        }
        qa {
            versionCode 778899
            versionName "v.1.0.BUILD_NUM"
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "VisualogyxQA"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", System.getenv("VISUALOGYX_HOST_QA") 
        }
        pro {
            versionCode 778899
            versionName "v.1.0.BUILD_NUM"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Visualogyx"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", System.getenv("VISUALOGYX_HOST_PRO")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "Visualogyx-${variant.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/XXX'
    }
}
```

Hope it works.Thanks.

Comment: This is something entirely new to me. I'll study more on this.
Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the new info.
Yes it is. I followed Wendy Lang's answer.

Comment: I did, regret to say my rep is too low for it to be recorded.